# English song similar to this track

Tags: pop

I have been trying to remember a song name for long but I could not. Luckily today I found a track which is little bit closer to the song I am searching for.

I used to hear English motivational songs in 2015 and had a playlist. I remember that this is from a male artist but l am not sure. The beat starts slow and then increases and implies a sense of urge to do something.

Similar track:  https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=Q9sDKN9IDqM

Please Check and help me find the song.

Comment: Since you've found your song and the answer is not likely to be of use to other people it would be a good idea to delete your question.

Answer (score 0):

Found it https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=A1adR-oXaZE&t=38s "we are the Warriors"

Comment: you can accept your own answer. Glad you found what you were looking for.  Could you maybe add some more details about the artist to your answer?